# Analyze timestamp data in Sas or R

Tags: r, loops, sas

I have a series of timestamp representing a user's activity on a website. I want to distinguish these timestamps into sessions (defined as timestamps less than an hour apart), calculate length of each session, and the gaps between session.

A sample dataset looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to loop through this series of timestamp in sas or R so that I could calculate the session length (eg: the 23:00 session in 01JUL14) and also calculate the gap between sessions (time lapse between July 1 and July 9)

Thanks!

Comment: First, you will need to define what a session is: Static definition (same day? No inactivity > 1 h? ...)? Or something like clustering?

Comment: Hi Martin, the session is defined as timestamps within an hour.

Comment: It would be better if you posted copy/paste-able sample data along with the desired output. That way we can test to make sure any possible suggestions are returning the values you want.

Comment: @MrFlick I've simplified this question into another one, please see here for the desired output. thx! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748191/mark-timestamps-into-session-in-sas

Answer (score 1):

```
# reproducible input data
dta <- data.frame(time = as.POSIXlt(c("2006-10-21 18:47:22",
                                      "2006-10-21 18:57:58",
                                      "2006-10-21 19:59:05",
                                      "2006-10-21 20:05:05",
                                      "2006-10-21 20:06:05",
                                      "2006-10-21 20:07:05",
                                      "2006-10-21 22:04:05",
                                      "2006-10-21 22:05:05")))
# see which timestamps are the start/stop of a session. 
# Hope that meets your definition of (inactivity less than) 1 hr for one session
dta$s.start <- c(TRUE, diff(dta$time) > 60)  # TRUE = start of new session, 60 min as max duration of a session
dta$s.stop  <- c(dta$s.start[2:length(dta$s.start)], TRUE) # TRUE = stop of this session

# indices of the timestamps that mar a session
sessions <- data.frame(
  s.1 = which(dta$s.start),  # starts
  s.2 = which(dta$s.stop))   # stops

# duration and gaps
(durations <- dta$time[sessions$s.2] - dta$time[sessions$s.1])
(gaps <- dta$time[sessions$s.1[2:length(sessions$s.1)]] - dta$time[sessions$s.2[1:length(sessions$s.2)-1]])
```